# What's wrong with my MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, sql-update

```
UPDATE table1 SET announcer = ( SELECT memberid
FROM ( table1
JOIN users ON table2.username = table1.announcer
) AS a
WHERE a.username = table1.announcer )
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'a where
>   a.username=table1.announcer)'
>   at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE announcements a
SET announcer =
(SELECT memberid
FROM users u
WHERE u.username = a.announcer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the JOIN in the UPDATE

```
UPDATE announcements JOIN users
SET announcements.announcer=users.memberid
WHERE announcements.username=users.username;
```

Note: For safty reasons (until your sure announcers get copied over right) I'd instead create a new column, say announcerNew then

```
UPDATE announcements JOIN users
SET announcements.announcerNew=users.memberid
WHERE announcements.username=users.username;
```