# How to write this MySQL update statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

How to write this MySQL update statement:

table1
identity

table2
memberid, username, email

Some values in identity of table1 are email, some are username, how to replace the values in identity of table1 with the corresponding value of memberid of table2?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question and had it answered?

Comment: No, this question didn't have been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table1.indentity = table2.memberid 
WHERE table1.FOREIGNKEYHERE = table2.PRIMARYKEYHERE;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference

```
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...

[WHERE where_condition]

[ORDER BY ...]

[LIMIT row_count]
```

from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

[Borrowed from MindStalker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934938/whats-wrong-with-my-mysql-statement/1934958#1934958):

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table1.identity=table2.memberid
WHERE table1.identity=table2.username or table1.identity=table2.email;
```